# Will I get bonus reputation when downvotes or other actions cause reputation to fall below 1, and then reversed?

Tags: discussion

I know that reputation never turns zero or negative, i.e. below +1.

Think about this situation: When I got 4 reputation, then got downvoted and -10 reputation, and later the downvotes are reversed. How my new reputation be calculated?

1. 4 - 3 + 4 = 4 (hit floor, reversed with 0 bonus)
2. 4 - 3 + 10 = 11 (hit floor, reversed with 7 bonus)

Comment: You go back to where you were as if the votes were never cast.

Comment: The exploit you're considering used to happen, but it's been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. When a downvote gets reversed, the *original event* literally gets reversed. So if there was no reputation change for that event, then there will be no reputation change to reverse when the vote gets reversed. You will not magically gain undeserved reputation.